# Spring message don't load in JSP

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, xslt

I have a **JSP** that loads another **JSP** that contains a **XSLT transformation.**

**JSP:1**

```
...
<div id="main_div">
      <-- load here -->
</div>
```

and in javascript I made a call `$('#main_div').load('page_name.htm',` ...

which goes to `MVC Controller`, return the **JSP:2** `url` that is loaded on **main_div**.

**JSP:2** contains only the **XLST** call

```
    <c:set var="xmltext">
        ${form.xmlResponse}
    </c:set>
    <c:import url="template.xsl" var="xslt"/>
    <x:transform xml="${xmltext}" xslt="${xslt}"/>
```

This call provides XML to XSLT, in order to return HTML code.

**XML**

```
<a>
  ...
  <country>EN</country>
  ...
</a>
```

Using `<spring:message code="table_country_code.EN"/>` tag, choose based on the browser language, the transalation into England, Inglaterra, etc...

**XSLT:**

```
<spring:message xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" code="table_country_code.{country}"/>
```

The problem is that I want to use `spring:message` in order to translate some fields through an i18n table, and the XSLT can produce me the tag , but don't convert the tag into the message of this code (i.e., the output in **JSP/HTML** is `<spring:message code="table_country_code.EN"/>` instead of England)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<spring:message code="table_country_code.EN"/>` instead of England it seems to me that your tag isn't parsed at all. Maybe you've missed the import of spring in your JSP ?